# D3 dendrogram straight edges

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Looking through the [documentation on d3.cluster()](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#cluster) I did not see anything that the developer can use to set the type of connecting line. It seems that there is only a curved spline kind of connection, but this is not the most conventional styling for dendrograms -- at least for my situation. What I'm after is a vertically oriented, 90 degree angle joined nodes:

[image]

### Question

Judging by the documentation, there is no direct built-in solution, but is there anything that `d3.cluster()` can offer to achieve the above result? Or am I better off coding everything from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has been asked before in [*"d3js Tree square"*](/q/11137238). However, I do not really consider this a duplicate as that old question was using D3 **v3** and, as it turns out, is not easily adapted to v5. Furthermore, you are explicitly asking for a vertical layout.

Nonetheless, the basic approach stays the same: just use a *custom path generator*. Building upon the old v3 [Block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2429963) this could be done as follows:

```
svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(root.links())
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", elbow);   // Appended paths use the custom path generator.

// Custom path generator    
function elbow(d) {
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "H" + d.target.x + "V" + d.target.y;
}
```

With some minor modifications to work with the v5 API Mike Bostock's demo can be rewritten as a [*Vertical "Elbow" Dendrogram*](https://bl.ocks.org/altocumulus/a5ad0c905cdbc2353bec012ea6883f03).

Note, that this is the same approach Mike Bostock used in his [Tree of Life](https://observablehq.com/@mbostock/tree-of-life) notebook where he used multiple custom path generators to create radial layouts.

Answer (score 2):

just had a similar need for creating an R-style dendrogram in d3 (→ JS).
The `dendrogram` function (bottom of this answer) produces dendrograms in the following style given the result of a call to [ml-hclust](https://github.com/mljs/hclust)

```js
dendrogram(hclust_result, { h: 2.5 })
```

[image]

(Here's an an accompanying notebook discussing hierarchical clustering in JS
https://observablehq.com/@chrispahm/hierarchical-clustering)

```js
function dendrogram(data, options = {}) {
  const {
    width: width = 420,
    height: height = 320,
    hideLabels: hideLabels = false,
    paddingBottom: paddingBottom = hideLabels ? 20 : 80,
    innerHeight = height - paddingBottom,
    innerWidth = width - 10,
    paddingLeft = 30,
    h: cutHeight = undefined,
    yLabel: yLabel = "↑ Height",
    colors: colors = d3.schemeTableau10,
    fontFamily: fontFamily = "Inter, sans-serif",
    linkColor: linkColor = "grey",
    fontSize: fontSize = 10,
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth = 1
  } = options;

  const svg = d3
    .create("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, innerHeight])
    .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

  var clusterLayout = d3.cluster().size([width - paddingLeft * 2, innerHeight]);

  const root = d3.hierarchy(data);
  const maxHeight = root.data.height;

  const yScaleLinear = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, maxHeight])
    .range([hideLabels ? innerHeight - 35 : innerHeight, 0]);

  const yAxisLinear = d3.axisLeft(yScaleLinear).tickSize(5);

  function transformY(data) {
    const height = hideLabels ? innerHeight - 15 : innerHeight;
    return height - (data.data.height / maxHeight) * height;
  }

  // traverse through first order children and assign colors
  if (cutHeight) {
    let curIndex = -1;
    root.each((child) => {
      if (
        child.data.height <= cutHeight &&
        child.data.height > 0 &&
        child.parent &&
        !child.parent.color
      ) {
        curIndex++;
        child.color = colors[curIndex];
      } else if (child.parent && child.parent.color) {
        child.color = child.parent.color;
      }
    });
  }

  clusterLayout(root);

  // y-axis
  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${hideLabels ? 20 : 0})`)
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${paddingLeft},${hideLabels ? 20 : 0})`)
    .call(yAxisLinear)
    .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call((g) =>
      g
        .append("text")
        .attr("x", -paddingLeft)
        .attr("y", -20)
        .attr("fill", "currentColor")
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .style("font-family", fontFamily)
        .text(yLabel)
    )
    .selectAll(".tick")
    .classed("baseline", (d) => d == 0)
    .style("font-size", `${fontSize}px`)
    .style("font-family", fontFamily);

  // Links
  root.links().forEach((link) => {
    svg
      .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("stroke", link.source.color || linkColor)
      .attr("stroke-width", `${strokeWidth}px`)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${paddingLeft}, ${hideLabels ? 20 : 0})`)
      .attr("d", elbow(link));
  });

  // Nodes
  root.descendants().forEach((desc) => {
    /*
    svg
      .append("circle")
      .classed("node", true)
      .attr("fill", desc.color)
      .attr("cx", desc.x)
      .attr("cy", transformY(desc))
      .attr("transform", `translate(${paddingLeft})`);
      .attr("r", 4);
    */
    if (desc.data.isLeaf && !hideLabels) {
      svg
        .append("text")
        //.attr("x", desc.x)
        .attr("dx", -5)
        .attr("dy", 3)
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .style("font-size", `${fontSize}px`)
        .style("font-family", fontFamily)
        .attr(
          "transform",
          `translate(${desc.x + paddingLeft},${transformY(desc)}) rotate(270)`
        )
        .text(desc.name || desc.data.index);
    }
  });

  // Custom path generator
  function elbow(d) {
    return (
      "M" +
      d.source.x +
      "," +
      transformY(d.source) +
      "H" +
      d.target.x +
      "V" +
      transformY(d.target)
    );
  }

  return svg.node();
}
```